What are these jumper components? Control Board from a Home Depot Minisplit
Not sure if these are some type of ferrite or something else but would like to know what they are (J8, J9). They are not labeled and are used in another place on the pcb as well. The board was shorted directly under these components by a service tech, destroying a trace to these jumpers/component?

net/ou3hJtA4.jpg

Reference designators with the letter J typically indicates a jumper.

They just look like jumpers. Probably for some sort of multiple configuration thing since it doesn't look like there's an underlying trace. Two in parallel and the size of the pours they're bridging suggests that they're carrying a bit of current. They don't appear to be damaged at all (or even really being capable of being damaged) so I'd look elsewhere for the source of the problem.

Probably a jumper seeing as how they are labeled J8 and J9, it looks like an 0603 or 0805 size judging by the size of the other components. Instead of using a 0 ohm resistor they are using some kind of metal jumper, you can put anything in there really that is conductive and wettable by solder.
Could also be a fuse...
(using wire flux remover wire is also a good use for not having a resistor)
